# How to import SBT project into IntelliJ Idea if the sources are broken?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-14

The problem is easy. I have some SBT project with some dependencies and existing sources. I want to change some dependency which needs updating the sources. After updating the dependency in an SBT file, the project needs to be refreshed in IntelliJ to load the new dependencies set. However, it fails to refresh because the plugin wants to compile the sources during import, which obviously leads to compilation errors (the sources needs to be updated for the new dependencies).

Is it a normal behaviour that SBT plugin compiles the whole project on import or it is a bug in my SBT project?

(IntelliJ Idea CE 15.0 EAP, up-to-date version of Scala plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the problem was in this line:

```
managedClasspath in IntegrationTest <<= Classpaths.concat(managedClasspath in IntegrationTest, exportedProducts in Test)
```

According to the hint provided by Nikolay Obedin in [SCL tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8822), I managed to solve the problem by changing the aforementioned line to:

```
(internalDependencyClasspath in IntegrationTest) <<= Classpaths.concat(internalDependencyClasspath in IntegrationTest, exportedProducts in Test)
```